# Auto Keying does not respect Active Keying Set in 2.8

Tags: animation, keyframes

How can I make Auto Keying respect the active keying set in 2.8?

Manually inserting keyframes with i in the viewport uses the active keying set properly. But the auto keying feature looks at it, scoffs, and does whatever it wants. Is there another setting somewhere? Is this a known bug?

Any help is appreciated.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a fresh copy of blender v 2.80 (i use the Steam version)
2. While keeping primal cube selected, change bottom view to Dope Sheet
3. Change Context to Action Editor
4. Create a new action
5. Change the bottom view to timeline
6. Open the Keying dropdown, and change Active Keying Set to Rotation
   [image]
7. Turn Auto Keying on
8. Rotate the cube in the main scene
9. In the timeline view, expand everything
10. You should see XYZ Location, Rotation and Scale keyframes

I would expect #10 to only have rotation keyframes. Nothing about Location or Scale.

Manually recording keyframes works fine:

Continue from step 6 above.

7. Rotate the cube in the main scene
8. Press i in the main scene
9. In the timeline view, expand everything
10. You should see XYZ Rotation only. Nothing about Location or Scale

Am I missing something? This makes auto keying useless for me :(

Comment: In 2.79 there is the option you want next to the Automatic Keyframe Insertion button, it allows to create keyframe only for the select active keying, I don't know where is this option in 2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @moonboots for pointing out where it was in 2.79. After looking around, I realized am blind...

If you open the Keying dropdown I used in my example above, the same button does exist in 2.8, is placed next to Add & Replace, and once you toggle it on, the auto function will start respecting the Keying Set.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Blender 3.x series, they moved this option again.  Now, when you turn on *Auto Keying*, there is a drop down box next to it that has the *Only Active Keying Set* option.

[image: Only Active Keying Set]